# Parse Messenger Chat Swift : Messages are out of order

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, chat, messenger

Recently I have been having a little trouble with my ios messenger. I fetched only text messages at first and everything worked perfectly. When I tried to fetch an image from parse I succeeded; however, the feed was not in the right order.
It seems like its ignoring "query.orderByAscending" entirely...

```
 fetchMessages()
 {
    currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()!
    let query = PFQuery(className:"Messages")
    query.whereKey("convoid", equalTo:convoid)
    query.orderByAscending("createdAt")
    query.cachePolicy = .NetworkElseCache
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            if let objects = objects {
              for object in objects {
                if(object["fileType"] as? String == "photo"){
                    if(object["senderId"] as? String == self.currentUser.objectId!){
                        let userImageFile = object["file"] as! PFFile
                        userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                            (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                            if error == nil {
                                let imageddata = UIImage(data:imageData!)
                                let chatBubbleData = ChatBubbleData(text: "", image:imageddata, date: object.createdAt, type: .Mine)
                                self.addChatBubble(chatBubbleData)
                                self.chatBubbleDatas.append(chatBubbleData)
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        let userImagefile = object["file"] as! PFFile
                        userImagefile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                            (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                            if error == nil {
                                let imageddata = UIImage(data:imageData!)
                                let chatBubbleData = ChatBubbleData(text: "", image:imageddata, date: object.createdAt, type: .Opponent)
                                self.addChatBubble(chatBubbleData)
                                self.chatBubbleDatas.append(chatBubbleData)

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    if(object["senderId"] as? String == self.currentUser.objectId!){
                        let chatBubbleData = ChatBubbleData(text: object["text"] as? String, image:nil, date: object.createdAt, type: .Mine)
                            self.addChatBubble(chatBubbleData)
                            self.chatBubbleDatas.append(chatBubbleData)
                    }else{
                        let chatBubbleData = ChatBubbleData(text: object["text"] as? String, image:nil, date: object.createdAt, type: .Opponent)
                            self.addChatBubble(chatBubbleData)
                            self.chatBubbleDatas.append(chatBubbleData)
                    }

                }
                }
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
        }
    }
    self.messageCointainerScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(messageCointainerScroll.frame), lastChatBubbleY + internalPadding)
    self.addKeyboardNotifications()
}
```

Everything works well besides the fact that the message view is not presenting all the messages in the right order. In fact, all the text messages are in the right order but an message image always comes after no matter what the case, regardless of the date createdAt. I think it has to do something with loading; however I am knew to swift and I am not completely sure. Any insights on a fix or a reference please share!

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that it has to do with the placement of your call to do operations on the main queue:

`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {`

You probably only want to do that when you need to update the user interface at the end. The issue is that the operations that take longer may get processed after the operations that take less time since the entire block is operating in the background to begin with (on a different queue, so you don't know what the scheduling is like on the main queue...).

Upon further inspection it appears you have a bunch of other background calls inside your block e.g.:

`userImagefile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock`

I have written code like this using Parse and JSQMessagesViewController which I assume is what you're doing. I strongly suggest you find ways to decouple your user interface updates from your model updates over the network. What you have right now is not only hard to debug but also probably causing your problem in some kind of hard to detect asynchronous way.

Comment: Thanks for the advice really appreciate it! I will definitely try to play around with ui updates and model updates through the network

Answer (score 0):

It is actually using `query.orderByAscending("createdAt")` to get the objects. Just add `print(objects)` inside `query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` and you should see all your objects printed in the right order.

The incorrect order is a result of loading the images. When you get a text object, you immediately append the data. But when the object is an image, you call `userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock` which downloads the image before calling the block which is where you append the data.

What you would need to do is append a placeholder for the image so it is in the correct position then update it when the image has finished downloading.

---

As a side note, you may want to look into [subclassing `PFObject`](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-subclasses), it will get rid of all the `as?` if statements and get rid of the [Pyramid of Doom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_of_doom_(programming)).

Comment: Interesting but where would the placeholder come into play? Would it be before? userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock ill definitely try to play with this thanks!

Comment: Yes, `userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock` is adding a delay which messes up the order. Adding the placeholder before that won't have a delay.

Comment: thank you much appreciated ill try to see if it works

Comment: weird, it put the images in the right sequence but the images were still presented after all the text